# printf formatting (%d versus %u)

Tags: c, pointers, formatting, printf

What is difference between `%d` and `%u` when printing pointer addresses?

For example:

```
int a = 5;
// check the memory address
printf("memory address = %d\n", &a); // prints "memory address = -12"
printf("memory address = %u\n", &a); // prints "memory address = 65456"
```

Answer (score 41):

You can find a list of formatting escapes on [this page](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

`%d` is a signed integer, while `%u` is an unsigned integer. Pointers (when treated as numbers) are usually non-negative.

If you actually want to display a pointer, use the `%p` format specifier.

Comment: Interesting that his example shows a negative value, then!  It depends on the machine, but I'd say addresses with a leading one-bit are fairly common on 32-bit machines, but less so on 64-bit machines.

Answer (score 19):

**%u** prints unsigned integer

**%d** prints signed integer

to get a pointer address use **%p**

### Other List of Formatting Escapes:

Here are the full list of formatting escapes. I am just giving a screen shot from [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly, you need `%p` to show the address that a pointer is using, for example:

```
int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int *p = &a;
    printf("%d, %u, %p", p, p, p);

    return 0;
}
```

will output something like:

```
-1083791044, 3211176252, 0xbf66a93c
```

Answer (score 1):

%u is used for unsigned integer. Since the memory address given by the signed integer address operator %d is -12, to get this value in unsigned integer, Compiler returns the unsigned integer value for this address.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simple: they cause different warning messages to be emitted when compiling:

```
1156942.c:7:31: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("memory address = %d\n", &a); // prints "memory add=-12"
                               ^
1156942.c:8:31: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("memory address = %u\n", &a); // prints "memory add=65456"
                               ^
```

If you pass your pointer as a `void*` and use `%p` as the conversion specifier, then you get no error message:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    // check the memory address
    printf("memory address = %d\n", &a); /* wrong */
    printf("memory address = %u\n", &a); /* wrong */
    printf("memory address = %p\n", (void*)&a); /* right */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

format specifier %u is used to print unsigned integer, whereas %d is used for signed integer.