# Trying to print structure variable without dot operator

Tags: arrays, c, structure

I am trying to print a structure variable simply without any dot or arrow operator.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct test{
        char A[10];
        float b;
    }obj = {"Testing",3.14};

    printf("%u\n",&obj);
    printf("%u\n",&obj.A);
    printf("%u\n",obj);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6422288
6422288
1953719636
```

See the third printf statement. I am simply trying to print the value of `obj`. Now i know it is something i am not supposed to do but i was just curious. The above two statements are simply printing the start address of the structure variable(assuming there is no pre structure padding involved here) but i am unable to understand what is happening in case 3. If it was an array of structure than simply writing `obj` would provide the base address of that array but what is the logic here ?

Comment: Could you add the print output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output, I know that your machine is little endian and has 4 byte `int`s.

In ASCII "Testing" is `{ 0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74 ... }`.  When you tell `printf` to use the `%u` format specifier for `unsigned int`, it looks at the first 4 bytes of the "value" of `obj`.  Interpretted as little endian, this is 0x74736554, which in base 10 is 1953719636, the value you see output.

Comment: Okay so if i use `%p` here, is this a valid behavior ? It is simply printing content(4 bytes) of variable like any other simple variable ?

Comment: @LocalHost: No - `%p` expects its corresponding argument to have pointer type, and `obj` is not a pointer.

Comment: So no matter what it will always be a UB. Right ?

Comment: @LocalHost: Correct.  There is no conversion specifier for `struct` objects.  You have to output each member separately.

Comment: yes, I made no mention of UB here since that was already covered.

Answer (score 4):

**Its all undefined behavior (UB)**

`printf("%u\n",&obj);` is UB as a pointer is not spec'd to match `"%u"`.  Same for  other 2.  All UB.

> but i am unable to understand what is happening in case 3

Recall that using a mis-matched print specifier is UB and can lead to non-sense output as the parameter passing mechanisms can differ by type.  E.g.  A FP value is passed in a FP stack and not the usual one resulting is `%u` accessing random data.

---

I recommend to use matching specifiers like `"%p"` for addresses, hex specifiers for numbers (`"%X"` `"%a"`) and hex constants (0x123, 1.23p45) when trying to divine UB.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  struct test {
    char A[10];
    float b;
  } obj = { "Testing", 3.14p0 };

  printf("%p\n", (void *) &obj);
  printf("%p\n", (void *) &obj.A);

  // Still UB, but if you get some output, possible easier to correlate to what is happening on your machine.
  printf("%llX\n", obj);
}
```

Comment: So if i simply use `%p` will it be a valid behavior ?

Comment: @LocalHost  A bit more - cast needed.  Using  `"%p"` with a `void *` as in `(void *) &obj` is specified behavior.  There is no matching print specifier for printing a `struct`.

Comment: Okay got it. So there is no way we can have a valid behavior for case 3 ?? I mean one should simply refrain from printing a struct variable ?

Comment: @LocalHost Yes.  Instead form a a helper function like `printf_test(const struct test *x)` that has `printf("desired  matching format", x->member1, x->member2, x->member3, ...);`

Comment: Smart Move :) . Thank btw.

Comment: @LocalHost On my machine, underneath the covers, a struct is passed by address, so %u ses the address.

Answer (score 2):

- `printf("%u\n",&obj);` prints the address where the struct starts, interpreted as an unsigned int.
- `printf("%u\n",&obj.A);` prints the addres of obj.A, interpreted as an unsigned int
- `printf("%u\n",obj);` prints the value of the struct, interpreted as an unsigned int.

Anyway, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156942/printf-formatting-d-versus-u)'s advice, for printing pointer values it's better to use `%p`.

Comment: what do you mean by value here? What will be a structure variable's value ?

Comment: Try a simple change, like this: `printf("%s\n", obj);` (note the `%s`) and see what magic happens. :-)

Comment: value: actual data in the address. Not the address itself, but the bytes written there.

Comment: Then I guess trying to refer to a `struct` on its own is undefined behaviour. clang-cl displays the "Testing" string.

Answer (score 1):

The address of the first element of a `struct` is the same as the address of the `struct` object itself<sup>1</sup>, so if you interpret the address of `obj` as a `char *`, then you can print the string stored in the first member like so:

```
printf( "%s\n", (char *) &obj );
```

However...

While tricks like this may give you some insight into how things work under the hood, they should be avoided in "real " code.  Life is easier for everyone if you use the member access operators as intended:

```
printf( "%s\n", obj.A );
```

---

1. Per the [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.2.7.1/15: "Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. **There may be unnamed
   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.**"

Comment: but what if there is a padding involved between where the structure object starts and where its first element starts ? Than both addresses can't be same.

Comment: @LocalHost I would guess there's never padding inserted at the beginning of a `struct` (just start at an aligned address), but don't know that to be a fact and will be interested if smarter people chime in.

Comment: @LocalHost: There is never any padding at the beginning of a `struct` object. Added the relevant language from the standard.